# How to display a few HTML objects based on input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sections as shown below

```
<div class="mbox">
People: John, Tim, Jake
Number : 5
<div>.

<div class="mbox">
People: John, Jake
Number : 6
<div>
```

Now, How is it possible to hide the above  when i give a user input of some sort to display all divs that have **Number > 6**. And also, another option to show sections that have **John,Jake**.

Can you suggest me how this can be done?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't even know your HTML code is invalid?

Secondly, looks like you can't modify your HTML code?

So the only solution is to select all the `.mbox`s and use `RegExp` to extract the number and filter the result like this:

```
$('.mbox').filter(function(){    
  return parseInt(RegExp("Number\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)").exec($(this).text())[1]) <= 6;    
}).css('display', 'none');
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/rVUEQ/)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do the job! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use data attribute of html to define the variable of the div.
ex: `<div class="mbox" data-number="5" data-name="..." > ... </div>`
Than i jquery you can select the attribute `$(".mbox").attr("data-number")` and make a control that check the number.
Same for the name but there depends is they are dynamics or statics.
If they are dynamics it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: using `attr("data-number")` should not be recommended, that's not the standard way to extract the custom data, use the `data("number")` instead.